# Button on HTML calling a google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have an code.gs that creates a menu that opens a sidebar with html.
My html is like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <button onclick='ativarFeedbacks()'>Feedback</button>
     <div id="aviso">aaasaaa</div>
     <script>
        
        function callback(resposta) {
           document.getElementById("aviso").innerHTML=resposta;
        }
     
        function ativarFeedbacks() {
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).escrever();
        }
        
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code.gs is like this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Configurar feedbacks', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('teste2')
      .setTitle('Feedback');
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function escrever(){
  return "<h1> salve salve </h1>"
}
```

But, when I run onOpen, I open the sidebar and press the button, nothing happens. My innerHTML on id "aviso" doesn't change like nothing was returned by escrever(). I am not understanding this behavior. What should I do?

Comment: If you're going to use type="button" then you should use input tag and not button.  Any way you should be able to debug this will the console and dev tools.  If you don't know how then this is a good time to learn.

Comment: To put it another way, the button element [doesn't have a type attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score 1):

The function `escrever()` doesn't exist. Use this instead:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).escreverFeedbacks();
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post it.

```
function escrever(){
  return "<h1> salve salve </h1>"
}
```